# number of days in date range - excel

Tags: excel, date, count, cell

I am new to excel and been struggling to find a way to get (`count`) the number of dates (i.e. `14`) from a cells `range` (i.e. `B1:B12`) considering that every cell has different date that not in sequence with the one in next cell.

Thanks.

`EDIT:`

Sorry I forgot to mention that I have time included with the date in each cell like the following:

Row: `1/2/2013 12:00:00 pm,1/2/2013 10:00:00 pm,5/9/2009 5:00:00 pm,1/2/2013,4/10/2013 1:00:00 am`I need a way to get number 3 for that row.

Comment: Post an example? what do you mean by "the number of date", the min and max date from the range?

Comment: @RémiBenoit
`Row: 1/2/2013,1/2/2013,5/9/2009,1/2/2013,4/10/2013 `
I need a way to get number 3 for that row.

Comment: So you want the min date of a row of date cells?

Comment: @RémiBenoit
I want to count the number of dates in each row. Please see the edit.

Comment: @iAziz Why number 3? How did you get that number?

Comment: @RémiBenoit 
Because of the following dates in the row `1/2/2013, 5/9/2009, 4/10/2013`. I have 5 dates with different times in 3 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(B2:B12,B2:B12)>0,1))
```

Reference:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-occurrences-of-values-or-unique-values-in-a-data-range-HP003056118.aspx

Edited:

Yes, according to comment from @barry, you can use `int` to drop the time, but you need to enter it as an array formula

```
{=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(INT(B2:B12),IF(B2:B12<>"",INT(B2:B12)))>0,1))}
```

Comment: If you have times in the range then use this version `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(INT(B2:B12),IF(B2:B12<>"",INT(B2:B12)))>0,1))` - also allows blanks (which won't be counted)

Comment: @sam092 and @barryhoudini
`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(INT(O2:O19), IF(O2:O19<>"",INT(O2:O19)) )>0,1))` 
it returns error #VALUE! And I don't know why! but thanks. EDIT: I'm using excel on mac

Comment: Have you entered it as an array formula?
Press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` to make it an array formula

Comment: @sam092 I'm using excel on Mac. How I can do this ?

Comment: @sam092 I needed to enter `(Command + Enter)` instead. It works perfectly! Thanks a lot guys.